# Ionic Page Not Displaying When I Add Authentication Code to Typescript Code

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, routes, ionic5

I am working on an Ionic project, but when I add code for firebase authentication to the typescript file, it stops working. I will include the code below and will appreciate any help. When I remove all the added to the login.page.ts it displays again. This shows the authentication code is what is causing the page not to display. All other pages without this code work.

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/member-ordering */
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-login',
  templateUrl: './new-login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-login.page.scss'],
})
export class NewLoginPage implements OnInit {
  credentials: FormGroup;

  constructor(public menuCtrl: MenuController,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private loadingController: LoadingController,
        private alertController: AlertController,
        private authenticationService: AuthService,
        private router: Router
) { }
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
   }

   get emailAddress(){
    return this.credentials.get('emailAddress');
   }

   get password(){
    return this.credentials.get('password');
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.credentials = this.formBuilder.group({
      emailAddress: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern(/@khalsaschool.ca$/), Validators.minLength(16)]],
      // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
      password: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.pattern(/\d/), Validators.pattern(/[a-z]/), Validators.pattern(/[A-Z]/)]]
    });
  }

    async createUser() {
        const loadin = await this.loadingController.create();
        await loadin.present();

        const user = await this.authenticationService.createUser(this.credentials.value);
        await loadin.dismiss();

        if (user) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home', { replaceUrl: true });
        } else {
            this.showAlert('Error', 'Create User Failed');
    }
    }

  async login() {

    const loadin = await this.loadingController.create();
        await loadin.present();

        const user = await this.authenticationService.login(this.credentials.value);
        await loadin.dismiss();

        if (user) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home', { replaceUrl: true });
        } else {
            this.showAlert('Error', 'Login Failed');
    }
  }

  async showAlert(header, message) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
            header,
            message,
            buttons: ['OK']
        });
        await alert.present();
  }
}
```

*/

Authentication service code

/*

```
// refference used to create this system
// https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-firebase-crud-operations/


// future required support for security rules
// https://medium.com/@juliomacr/10-firebase-realtime-database-rule-templates-d4894a118a98


// storage and authentication
// https://devdactic.com/ionic-firebase-auth-upload

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataServiceService {

  collectionName = 'test';

  constructor(private database: AngularFirestore) { }


// function to access, create, modify, and delete data

createData(data) {
  return this.database.collection(this.collectionName).add(data);
}

readData() {
  return this.database.collection(this.collectionName).snapshotChanges();
}

updateData(id, data) {
  return this.database.doc(this.collectionName + '/' + id).update(data);
}

deleteData(id) {
  return this.database.doc(this.collectionName + '/' + id).delete();
}

}
```

*/

Comment: Can you show what is the content of your authentication service? Also what Firebase Authentication package are you using? Is it AngularFire?

Comment: @dvbngln I am using AngularFire 7 --> @angular/fire": "^7.4.1"

Comment: @dvbngln code above